# Position in string builder

Tags: java, buffer, stringbuilder, charsequence

I have a class `CustomBuffer` that implements `Appendable`, `CharSequence` and extends `Buffer`. It uses a `charBuffer` to access elements. Since it takes some time in computation I am planning to replace it with a `StringBuilder`. Unfortunately my current class uses methods like `position`, `flip` from `Buffer` class, which is not available in `StringBuilder` class. In order to use those I have two options,

1. `StringBuilder` extend `Buffer` (I am not sure whether its a right option as I have not used Buffers much)
2. Otherwise use the methods I mentioned my modifying the resources from `StringBuilder`.

I am providing sample code.

Current scenario:

```
public void write(Object object, CustomBuffer cba)
            throws Exception {
     CustomBuffer cb = new CustomBuffer();
     String str = getString(cb.position(), (String)object.size());
     cb.flip();
     cba.append(str);
     cba.append(cb.toString());
   }
```

If I have to replace with `StringBuilder` how can I reproduce the same effect. Definitely I cannot provide the index to get position according to the structure of the code, it would be great if I get some help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you managing so low levels char maniplations ?
What the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I have computation time to be very high for using CustomClass, I want to replace it using existing library classes and reduce time.

Comment: If you're just appending char or strings you should use StringBuilder. But I have not a clue of what you're doing with your CustomBuffer. Why do you need extends Buffer and what is the role of your CustomBuffer class ?

Comment: This method is a simple one, apart from this CustomBuffer is used to iterate over different levels of strings one within other, it consists of supporting methods for such actions.

Comment: That method makes no sense at all. The freshly created buffer should have the initial position of `0`, so `cb.position()` can be replaced by `0`. Then, your doing `(String)object.size()`… really? So `Object` is not `java.lang.Object` and it has a `size()` method that returns something that can be cast to `String`? Great, but what’s the point of the subsequent `cb.flip()`? Up to that point, you didn’t do anything with `cb` besides asking for its (initial) position. Unless some unspecified magic happens, on the last `cba.append(cb.toString());`, `cb` still is in its initial empty state.

Comment: So the entire method can be reduced to `cba.append(getString(0, (String)object.size()));`, whatever that means to the specified `Object` argument…